# Catch those sheep!

Tags: code-golf

You're a farmer and your flock of sheep has escaped!  Oh no!

Round up those sheep by building fences to contain them.  As a farmer on a budget you want to use the least amount of fence possible.  Luckily for you though, they aren't the smartest sheep in the world and don't bother moving after having escaped.

## Task

Given a list of coordinates, output the least amount of fence segments necessary to contain the sheep.

## Rules

- Sheep are contained if they cannot wander off (no holes in the fence).
- You do not have to contain all the sheep in one block of fence - there could be multiple fenced-off areas independent from each other.
- Fence segments are oriented in cardinal directions.
- Each coordinate tuple represents a single sheep.
- Input must be positive integer pairs, `x>0` & `y>0`, but can be formatted appropriately for your language.

  - i.e.: `{{1,1},{2,1},{3,7}, .. }` or `[1,2],[2,1],[3,7], ..`
- Empty spaces inside a fenced-off area are okay.
- You cannot assume coordinates are input in any specific order.

For example, a single sheep requires `4` fence segments to be fully contained.

## Test cases

```
[1,1]
4

[1,1],[1,2],[2,2]
8

[2,1],[3,1],[2,3],[1,1],[1,3],[3,2],[1,2],[3,3]
12

[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[3,7],[4,9],[4,10],[4,11],[5,10]
22

[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9]
36

[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9]
32

[2,1],[8,3],[8,4]
10
```

**Notes**

- You can assume input coordinates are valid.
- Your algorithm should theoretically work for any reasonably large integer coordinate (up to your language's maximum supported value).
- Either full program or function answers are okay.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Can input be a list of x coordinates, followed by a list of y coordinates? e.g. `{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8} -> {1,5},{2,6},{3,7},{4,8}`

Comment: @Phoenix Nope, each `x,y` input must be together. Nice thought though, I hadn't thought of that myself.

Comment: What are the bounds on the coordinates? Are 0s and negatives possible?

Comment: @AGourd For simplicity, positive integers.  Thanks, edited the question to clarify.

Comment: This is surprisingly hard. Every time I think I have a heuristic that handles all cases, there's something I missed.

Comment: _"Multiple sheep can occupy the same space"_: It's a bit late, but I'd suggest to remove this rule which doesn't add anything to the challenge.

Comment: @Arnauld You're absolutely right, I changed the test case and didn't update the output.  My apologies.

Comment: In regards to _multiple sheep can occupy the same space_, I wanted to make sure input algorithms could handle duplicate coordinates.

Comment: I see your point. But IMHO, multiple sheep occupying the same space should not be permitted at all. (The challenge is still hard enough without that. ^^)

Comment: @Arnauld Good point.  Fair enough.  :)  I'll remove that line, but I'm unsure if modifying the criteria further is kosher at this point.  Perhaps _"you can assume input coordinates are valid"_ covers this.

Comment: Can I assume there's at least one sheep?

Comment: @isaacg Yes.  :-)

Comment: Downgoat is going to love this challenge!

Comment: Wow, what a challenge. I concede my loss; screw doing this in 05AB1E.

Comment: You should include a test case where the fenced area must contain empty coordinates next to a fence, e.g. `[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[3,1],[3,3]`

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>251</s> <s>244</s> 275 bytes

```js
a=>Math.min(...(P=(a,r=[[a]],c=a[0])=>(a[1]&&P(a.slice(1)).map(l=>(r.push([[c],...l]),l.map((_,i)=>r.push([[c,...l[i]],...((b=[...l]).splice(i,1),b)])))),r))(a).map(L=>L.reduce((p,l)=>l.map(([h,v])=>(x=h<x?h:x,X=h<X?X:h,y=v<y?v:y,Y=v<Y?Y:v),x=y=1/0,X=Y=0)&&p+X-x+Y-y+2,0)))*2
```

#### How?

We use the recursive function ***P()*** to create a list of all possible partitions of the input list. This function is currently sub-optimal, in that it's returning some duplicated partitions -- which does not however alter the final result.

For each partition, we compute the number of fences required to surround all sheep in each group with a rectangle. The sum of these fences gives the score of the partition. We eventually return the lowest score.

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>Math.min(...(P=(a,r=[[a]],c=a[0])=>(a[1]&&P(a.slice(1)).map(l=>(r.push([[c],...l]),l.map((_,i)=>r.push([[c,...l[i]],...((b=[...l]).splice(i,1),b)])))),r))(a).map(L=>L.reduce((p,l)=>l.map(([h,v])=>(x=h<x?h:x,X=h<X?X:h,y=v<y?v:y,Y=v<Y?Y:v),x=y=1/0,X=Y=0)&&p+X-x+Y-y+2,0)))*2

console.log(f([[1,1]]))
console.log(f([[1,1],[1,2],[2,2]]))
console.log(f([[2,1],[3,1],[2,3],[1,1],[1,3],[3,2],[1,2],[3,3]]))
console.log(f([[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[3,7],[4,9],[4,10],[4,11],[5,10]]))
console.log(f([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9]]))
console.log(f([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9]]))
console.log(f([[2,1],[8,3],[8,4]]))
```

Comment: About step 2, why not `[ [1,1],[2,2] ] , [ [1,2] ]` ?

Comment: @edc65 Hopefully it should now be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)), <s>62 58 57</s> 55 bytes

```
{+//2*1+{(|/x)-&/x}'(x@?(&|/2>(|/'{x|-x}x-\:)')')/,:'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY49DsIwDIWv4qlJaKMQpz9pLQEHYe7SgdVSk7OnDmVBIMtP9nufJW/2tZWyLnvrHF58u@vk2NjGcVaaH3fdJIc3MdXOyXJm@1yMknLdojiXVenOgyddxQMSAhrSKFuQRgh0JkF2fBMBgvnixZmoh1naX6t4GmT6QCcQxO/FHmiEkSY5iBBphvkP9UvUd6KkEXpjygE)